# Direct Stream Digital (DSD) editing software, no PCM

Tags: sound-editing, audio-editor, pcm

What editing programs work with Direct Stream Digital (DSD) audio without changing to PCM first? In other words, software that stays in the DSD format from beginning to end? Free would be a bonus.   :-)

I've ordered a Sony PCM D100 recorder which offers DSD recording so I might as well try that format and listen for myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex question =-)

there's only one software that allows for true DSD editing, Sonoma Systems. This software however relies on sound card dependencies.

DSD cannot be edited because there's only one bit, therefore it cannot be manipulated. At the point of edit Sonoma converts the audio to multi-bit DSD, and then goes back to 1bit after the edit. This allows for manipulation at the point of the edit. (This is similar to PCMs 32bit float)

The other software that allows for editing DSD is Pyramix. It however, doesnt stick with DSD. At any edit point it converts to DXD (Incredibly high resolution PCM) then back to DSD. So, digital conversions are happening at every edit point.

Now for a cheap option, you can go for the [Korg AudioGate](http://www.korg.com/us/products/audio/audiogate4/) Software. This is for playback and not editing but you can do basic fade-in/out and cutting a song up. But this wouldn't work well for multi-track recordings, but you can take 2 mono DSD files and create stereo interleaved file.

**Here's a great website that has info on DSD (and some free downloads): [DSD-Guide.com](http://dsd-guide.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it can be edited with programs like Tascam Hi-Res Editor:

http://tascam.com/product/hi-res_editor/

From their site:

> TASCAM Hi-Res Editor is a new, free application that plays and edits up to 11MHz DSD or 384kHz WAV files. The software allows playback and export of DSD files without converting to PCM audio. This app is available now as a free download for Windows and Mac.